# Use custom numeric keyboard on iPad only

Tags: swift, ipad, numeric-keypad

New to iPad development. I would like to use a custom numeric keyboard (using a pod) on iPad, but the native one on iPhones. Is it possible to make an extension on UITextField, UITextView to set/get inputView/keyboardType? Or is there an other solution?

```
myTextField.keyboardType = .decimalPad

extension UITextField {
    ....

    case .decimalPad:
       if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom input view using the `inputView` property of `UITextField`. If it is not set, the default keyboard (as configured on the text field) will appear when the text field becomes first responder. So only set if to your custom numeric keyboard view when running on iPad and leave it as-is on iPhone.

**EDIT**

Initially I pointed out `inputAccessoryView` instead of `inputView`, hence the confusion in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, could I override the inputAccessoryView property somehow without subclassing or do I need to set it for each UITextField in the app? (Without any changes the custom keyboard appears in the middle of the screen, using inputAccessoryView..)

Comment: My bad, you want `inputView` not `inputAccessoryView`... sorry for mixing them up. `inputView` actually replaces the keyboard. No need to subclass, just set a view to that property.

Comment: Thanks, wondering if there is a way to set the `inputView` property _once_ for all UITextFields in the app - "if iPad"? I suppose I have to make a subclass of UITextField, since the property cannot be overridden in an extension?

Comment: If you don't want to subclass you can add an extension with a static factory method a la `withPlatformSpecificKeyboard`, which encapsulates the platform-dispatching logic; you'd use this factory instead of the standard initializer to create `UITextField` instances.